# Is it possible to upload file to web api by calling Register method in Accounts controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have to upload user photo while registering a new user.The data from WPF application must consume the register method and inserts user detail and photo.
The register method accepts RegisterBindingModel , and i passed the model
properties in body as raw with content-type application json.But i am not able to upload file.

I know ,for uploading file we use form-data and we can pass additional parametes
in form data along with the file.But I need to get the file in api Register action method.

I have searched many articles and found files are uploading to api using form data.But those api methods does not accepts any input parameter.

Comment: if u can make change in RegisterBindingModel, then u can convert your image in base64 format and put it in a new string field of model. You can convert to image from base64 at server side....... there might be other solution but this seems quick to me.

Comment: It works....I learned a new method of consuming file(s) in web api

Comment: can u mark my comment as usefull.... :) thanks

Comment: Sorry,rght now I did not have the provision for that...